# Getting child element of a child element of a parent with ID

Tags: javascript, children

I need to get to the child of the child of the child of an element with an id = "part1" with javascript. So essentially, I want to get to the 3rd row of the 3rd table of the span element but I can't seem to get it to work :(

```
<span id = "part1">
<table> </table>
<table> </table>
<table>
    <tr> ... </tr> 
    <tr> ... </tr> 
    <tr> ... </tr> (get this row)
</table>
</span>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Non-jQuery solution

```
var span = document.getElementById('part1');
var row = span.getElementsByTagName('table')[2].childNodes[2];
```

#### jQuery solution

Using `:eq` selector:

```
var $row = $('#part1 > table:eq(2) > tr:eq(2)');
```

Using `:nth-child` selector:

```
var $row = $('#part1 > table:nth-child(3) > tr:nth-child(3)');
```

`:eq` and `:nth-child` selectors selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent. However `:eq` follows "0-indexed" counting and `nth-child` follows "1-indexed".

Be aware that `:eq` and `nth:child` selectors work differently. In this case it would do the same because you only have `table` elements inside `span#part1`.

**From jQuery documentation:**

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even
>   though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements.
>   With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class. With :eq(n) only the selector
>   attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of
>   any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

**Reference:**

[**:nth-child() Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: Thank you - could you just quickly explain the use of eq - just to put your answer into context for me :)

Comment: Thank you :) I've just run into an error with my JQUERY library not linking to my site - so I'll get cracking on that

Comment: I just saw your comment :) many thanks! If I end up wanting to go another level deeper in terms of the child node would i say "row.childNodes[#]" ?

Comment: Non-Jquery one liner: var row = document.querySelector('#part1 > table:nth-child(3) > tr:nth-child(3)')

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
this.parentNode().getElementsByTagName("table")[2].childNodes[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `.find()` rather than the sizzle engine. Something like this:

```
var TheThirdRow = $('#part1').find('table')
                             .eq(2)
                             .find('tr')
                             .eq(2);
```

Comment: is there a reason for your preference?  I find() more efficient?

Comment: @nueverest: yes, anytime you have an expression $(SomeSelector) it needs to be evaluated with the Sizzle engine first so that jQuery knows which element to work with. If you start with an element with an ID in the selector $('#SomeID'), it skips all the initial computation and perf tests show that.